# Impala EOMONTH equivalent

Tags: sql, impala

My problem is that EOMONTH doesn't seem to exist in Impala so I was hoping there is a substitute for EOMONTH. I just want to only return the values that correspond with end of month dates. Below is the query I tried and the last line is where I have the problem.

```
SELECT a.ticker,a.FieldName,a.DataSource,b.tickervalue, 
to_timestamp(CAST(tickervaluedate/1000 as bigint)) as tickervaluedate
FROM agronomycn.raw_crttickername AS a 
INNER JOIN agronomycn.raw_crttickervalue as b on a.TickerID = b.TickerID
WHERE a.ticker = 'C_FRONT2' AND a.fieldname = 'CLOSE' AND a.datasource = 'EXCH'
AND to_timestamp(CAST(b.tickervaluedate/1000 as BIGINT)) BETWEEN '2010-01- 01' AND '2019-01-01' 
AND to_timestamp(CAST(b.tickervaluedate/1000 as BIGINT)) = EOMONTH(to_timestamp(CAST(b.tickervaluedate/1000 as BIGINT)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of `trunc`,`add_months` and `date_add`.

```
select date_add(add_months(trunc(dtCol,'MM'),1),-1)
```

This assumes the string format of date is `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: So when I change my last line to AND to_timestamp(CAST(b.tickervaluedate/1000 as BIGINT)) = date_add(add_months(trunc(to_timestamp(CAST(b.tickervaluedate/1000 as BIGINT)),'MM'),1),-1), I don't retrieve any values so I am assuming I am using this wrong

Comment: the format is timestamp but it's raw form is unixtime

Comment: ticker fieldname datasource tickervalue tickervaluedate
  ticker fieldname datasource tickervalue tickervaluedate
1 C_FRONT2 CLOSE EXCH 382.25 2018-11-12 06:00:00
2 C_FRONT2 CLOSE EXCH 377.75 2018-11-13 06:00:00

Comment: just use `date_add(add_months(trunc(b.tickervaluedate,'MM'),1),-1)` to get the month end date.

Comment: Yes that returns month end date but I want to only see values where it is a month end date for example values where date is 2018-12-31, 2018-11-30, etc.

Comment: compare it with the actual truncated part of date..`date_add(add_months(trunc(b.tickervaluedate,'MM'),1),-1) = to_date(b.tickervaluedate)`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.